# How can I get old cloud-watch logs in node js lambda code (aws-sdk)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get old cloud watch logs into my lambda code and update it in some other db. I want to use AWS-SDK solution so that i can write code in NODEJS to get some changes in logs n save it to some other DB

Answer (score 2):

`GetLogEvents` method may work for you.

> Lists log events from the specified log stream. You can list all the log events or filter using a time range.
>
> By default, this operation returns as many log events as can fit in a response size of 1MB (up to 10,000 log events). You can get additional log events by specifying one of the tokens in a subsequent call.

here is the [link for details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchLogs.html#getLogEvents-property)